# Анимация в Unity не допускает изменения позиции через transform.Translate(direction * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

Tags: c#, unity3d

Анимация сделана через **Position**, я использую `transform.Translate(direction * Time.fixedDeltaTime);` для перемещения x, без анимации работает, с анимацией нет.

Объект будто закреплен именно на этой позиции, даже через стрелки не могу перемещать во время игры